# "It may not seem" vs "It may seem not"

Tags: negation, auxiliary-verbs

Are these 2 examples both grammatically valid? Are there any differences in the tone or the meaning?

A. It may not seem strange.
B. It may seem not strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case B. ("seem not strange") is rare to the point of oddity. It's used in two instances. The first is to bring a contrasting phrase with *but* close to the negation:

From *The Last Guardian of Everness* by J C Wright (2007):

> **[1]** As in a dream shall all things **seem, not strange**, *but* familiar,....

The second is in conjunction with the now little-used *subjunctive mood*. From *The Metaphysical Poets* by T James (1988)

> **[2]** [I]f by any occasion they *be* lost it ***seem* not strange** to us to pass it over.

Both A. and B. are grammatical and they mean the same thing, but given the age of some of the examples and the appearance of the construct in poetry, B. has (to me) a slightly archaic or literary tone.

Comment: As a general rule, it's the verb _ to seem_ which is negated rather than the adjective, unless it's a negative adjective (_It may seem unpleasant..._)

Comment: @KateBunting *Seem* means to have some impression from the senses. I doubt that the verb is negated in "not seem." What would that opposite state entail, being insensate? Look at [1] and transpose to "a dream shall not seem strange but familiar." The dream still makes an impression, one of familiarity.

Comment: I meant simply that we usually say that something _does not seem [adjective]_ rather than _seems [not adjective]_, unless the adjective itself includes a negative. However , _seems not to be [adjective]_ is possible.